# Swiftui coredata foreach scrollview : delete button

Tags: swift, button, core-data, delete-row

I'm trying to add delete button on each list. (not using swipe function)

This is my current summary code.

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: Saving.entity(), sortDescriptors: [
        NSSortDescriptor(KeyPath: \Saving.orders, ascending: true),
        ~~~
    ]
    ) var savings : FetchedResults<Saving>
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false){
                ForEach(savings, id : \.self) { save in
                    ZStack{
                        HStack(alignment: .top){
                            Menu(content: {Button(action: {
                                                    self.delete(at:IndexSet.init(arrayLiteral: 0))}) {
                                Text("Delete")
                                Image(systemName: "trash")}
                            })  {
                                Image(systemName:"line.horizontal.3")}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        for index in offsets {
            let deletes = saving[index]
            self.moc.delete(deletes)
        }
        try! self.moc.save()
    }
}
```

I can designate the index number at button action and when i tap the button in the list which has a lat of rows, i can delete only the first row again and again. It just like when i tap the delete button in any row, the first row is always deleted. it's obvious cause the index number is 0.
I want to delete the row when i tap the button in that row.
How can i fix this problem?
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass correct index insted of ```IndexSet.init(arrayLiteral: 0)``

So use `indices` and first find the index and pass as an Int index.
Like this,

Body view

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false){
                ForEach(savings.indices, id : \.self) { index in //<--- Here
                    let save = savings[index] //<--- Here
                    ZStack{
                        HStack(alignment: .top){
                            Menu(content: {Button(action: {
                                                    self.delete(at: index)}) { //<--- Here
                                Text("Delete")
                                Image(systemName: "trash")}
                            })  {
                                Image(systemName:"line.horizontal.3")}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Delete function

```
func delete(at index: Int) { //<--- Here
        let deletes = saving[index]
        self.moc.delete(deletes)
    try! self.moc.save()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I tried to apply your solution to my code but i got this compiler error at 'var body: some View'. Here is the error message 'The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions' How can i fix this? Thank you again!

Comment: It means you have so many codes inside the body. just try to break and separate body code.

Comment: You're right! When i delete some codes in the var body: some View, it works! So, i tried to break and make a body code (one of the VStack codes) outside the var body: some View using private var some View. but i don't know how to use 'save' (let save = savings[index], it is needed because i use it for ForEach code) in separate body code. Can you help me again? Thanks a lot!